# Shading an area boundered by a curve

Tags: matlab

What would be the easiest way to lightly shade (or hatch; or anything to set it different from the rest) an area in a plot(), below a curve y=x^2, for example ?

```
x = 0:pi/10:2*pi;  
y = x.^2.;
plot(x,y);
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`area(x,y)`](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/area.html) should do the trick. I'm not sure if that class has a FaceAlpha property though.

**EDIT:** Unfortunately, the area class doesn't have a FaceAlpha property. But you can work around that and edit the patch directly:

```
x=0:pi/10:2*pi;
y=x.^2;
H=area(x,y);
h=get(H,'children');
set(h,'FaceAlpha',0.5); %#Tada!
```

**EDIT2:** To shade the area above the curve, you could use a second area plot with a white fill. It's kind of a kludge, but it should work. Starting over:

```
x=0:pi/10:2*pi;
y=x.^2;
y2=max(y)*ones(size(y));
hold on
H1=area(x,y2);
H2=area(x,y);
set(H2,'FaceColor',[1 1 1]);
axis tight
```

or building on Jason S's solution, use the baseval input to shade above the curve:

```
x=0:pi/10:2*pi;
y=x.^2;
baseval=max(y);
H=area(x,y,baseval);
h=get(H,'children');
set(h,'FaceAlpha',0.5,'FaceColor',[0 1 0]);
axis tight
```

Comment: I'm still getting used to matlab's ways, so excuse if this simple question. But where do you set the color in those 3 lines ? And how for example would you shade an area above the curve with that principle ?

Comment: shade area above the curve: no need to kludge. See my answer.

Comment: @Jason S: good point. I didn't know you could set baseval above the points in the curve! +1

Comment: Instead of setting FaceAlpha on the child patch, you could set FaceColor directly on the area handle. It would not be transparent but you can achieve the same light shade.

Comment: @Yair Altman: True, I wrote my answer under the assumption that there were other curves/points/etc plotted on the same axis.

Answer (score 5):

A supplemental example to elaborate on Doresoom's post:

```
x=0:pi/50:2*pi;
y1=x.^2;
y2=10+5*sin(3*x);
baseval1=20;
baseval2=3;
clf;
hold on;
H1=area(x,y1,baseval1);
H2=area(x,y2,baseval2);
hold off;
h=get(H1,'children');
set(h,'FaceAlpha',0.5,'FaceColor',[1 0.5 0]);
  % set color to orange, alpha to 0.5
h=get(H2,'children');
set(h,'FaceAlpha',0.5,'FaceColor',[0.85 1 0.25]);
  % set color to yellow-green, alpha to 0.5
```

> But where do you set the color ?

h is a handle to a patch (a filled in area); if you type get(h) you can see all its properties. The [MATLAB docs on `patch` properties](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/patch_props.html) explain these to some degree.

> And how for example would you shade an area above the curve with that principle ?

`area` creates a patch between a base value and a curve. Doesn't look like there's an easy way to create an area between two curves though.

Answer (score 0):

Without messing with `children`, you can also:

```
x = 0:pi/10:2*pi;  % from your example
y = x.^2.;    % from your example

H=area(x,y);
set(H(1),'FaceColor','k');
alpha(.5);
```

Worked for me, it also helped with some `legend` issues that I was having.

. To kick a dead question