# Shading between vertical lines in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, area

I'm sure this is a simple question, but I can't seem to figure it out. I've got this plot
[image]

and I want to add vertical lines and shade the area in between to highlight areas of the data. I feel like I should be able to do this using the area function, but can't seem to figure it out. The dates and values are all doubles and are two separate vectors, if that makes a difference. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Very basic example about shading an area in a plot. [Shading an area boundered by a curve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2820018/shading-an-area-boundered-by-a-curve) might be of interest as well.

```
figure;
ha = area([4 6], [10 10]);
hold on
plot(1:10, 1:10,'r')
axis([1 10 1 10])
hold off
```

[image: shaded area]

Comment: Thank you very much. The doc for area was way too confusing.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `area`, you can also use `fill`, which can be a bit more intuitive in terms of usage.

```
figure;
plot(1:10, 1:10,'r');

% Define the "shading"
% Note how each x_points(i) corresponds to y_points(i)
x_points = [5, 5, 7, 7];  
y_points = [0, 10, 10, 0];
color = [0, 0, 1];

hold on;
a = fill(x_points, y_points, color);
a.FaceAlpha = 0.1;
```

[image: a matlab figure]