# matlab area color under function

Tags: matlab, colors, area

I have a function in a table :

```
tab = [1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1];
figure;plot(tab);
```

And i would like to draw area color under the fucntion like that:
[image]

I found the easy solution by myself :

```
clear all;close all;
x=[1 2 3 4 5 5 5 6 7];
plot(x);

hold on;
x1=[1 2 3]; %plage x
y1 = [1 2 3];
y2 = [0 0 0];
X=[x1,fliplr(x1)];
Y=[y1,fliplr(y2)];
fill(X,Y,'b'); 

hold on;
x2=  [5 6 7 8 9];
y3 = [5 5 5 6 7];
y4 = [0 0 0 0 0];
X1=[x2,fliplr(x2)];
Y1=[y3,fliplr(y4)];
fill(X1,Y1,'r');
```

Comment: Here is a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2820018/shading-an-area-boundered-by-a-curve

Comment: I'm sorry but i don't understand this example.

Comment: There is this `area` solution, but there are some more using patch or fill. You may want to use `fill` along with the `fliplr` function (see https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/115510). Tons of example on the web...

Comment: Look at my edit post please, i find that answeres are very complicate for my example.
I don't think it's fliplr no ?
There is no an easy way just to do this like:

fill(tab,2,3,red);
fill(tab,5,7,blue);

Comment: Use `fill([2 3 3 2], [tab(2) tab(3) 1 1], 'r')`. Not tested though.

Comment: No it doesn't work. I don't understand why it's so hard to do this, just to color area under function and y=0

Comment: Actually my code works. Full version: `tab = [1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1];
figure;plot(tab);
hold on;
fill([2 3 3 2], [tab(2) tab(3) 1 1], 'r')`. And nice job searching & finding the solution by yourself ;)